# code to find specific file(s) according to name pattern - problem with break command

Tags: python

I am a python newbie and this is my first question. I would be really grateful for any hints.

I wrote a piece of code which iterates over the files in a specified folder to look for a file whose name matches a regex pattern (a part of the file name). The code sort of works, but I have a problem with it. Please have a look and I'll explain afterwards:

```
import re, os, sys

basedir = '/home/user_name/python_files'

print('Please specify DG, year and dossier number.')
print()
DG = input('DG: ')
year = str(input('Year: '))
dossier = str(input('Dossier: '))

fileregex = DG + '-'+ year + '-' + dossier

for r, d, f in os.walk(basedir):
    for file in f:
        if re.match(fileregex, file, re.I):
            print('I found the file', file, 'in', os.path.join(r))
            break
    else:
        print('File not found')
```

When the code finds the file, it prints out its name and breaks; when it doesn't, it prints out `File not found`. So far, so good. However, the code breaks after it finds the first match and I want it to keep looking for other matches.

If I remove the `break` statement, it finds other (partially matched) files, but it also prints out `File not found`.

How to make sure that the code breaks only **after** it has found all the matches and prints out `File not found` only when it doesn't find any matches?

Thanks.
Greg

Comment: You don't need the `for-else` construct. Try and think about another way to express what you want. Hint: one way is to use a flag variable. But see if there is another more elegant solution :)

Comment: Maybe think about using "While". An example would be to nest some of your code in a while loop as so:   while allMatchesNotFound == False...do stuff. Else: all matches found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save all the matches in a list. Then if there are no matches, the list would have a length of 0, so you then can check for the length of the list to see, if there were any matches.

```
matches = []
for r, d, f in os.walk(basedir):
    for file in f:
        if re.match(fileregex, file, re.I):
            matches.append((file, os.path.join(r)))

if len(matches) == 0:
    print('File not found')
else:
    for file, path in matches:
        print(f'This file was a match: {file} and was found: {path}')
```

Comment: He wants the he directory too

Answer (score 1):

## May use a list to store your data and check afterwards if list is empty or not

Here's my solution

```
files = []
for r, d, f in os.walk(basedir):
    for file in f:
        if re.match(fileregex, file, re.I):
            files.append([file, os.path.join(r)])

if len(files) > 0:
     for file in files:
         print(f"I found a file {file[0]} in {file[1]}")
else:
     print('File not found')
```